# Simple HTML Page with Ajax not working

Tags: jquery

I just started to get an idea of AJAX. For this i am trying out an example i found while searching on my local machine. But it is not working.

The page has some static text when page is loaded, once we scroll down, new dynamic text is added using ajax, but its not adding new text while scrolling.

The html file code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                sendData();
            }
        });

        function sendData() {
            $.ajax(
             {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "https://localhost/kailash/cgi/testing/getdata.pl",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 async: "true",
                 cache: "false",

                 success: function (msg) {
                     $("#myDiv").append(msg.d);
                 },

                 Error: function (x, e) {
                     alert("Some error");
                 }

             });

        }

    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="myDiv">

    <p>
        Static data initially rendered.
    </p>
```

It calls getdata.pl. Code in getdata.pl is

```
our $resp;
my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header();

$resp = "<p>This content is dynamically appended to the existing content on scrolling.</p>";
return "$resp\n";
```

So this is not working. can you please help me in getting it working.
Please let me know whats missing in it.

Comment: Define 'not working' are you getting an JS error?

Comment: Is your page long enough to scroll the specified amount? Further, replace == for >=, otherwise you need to scroll an exact amount of pixels.

Comment: No error as such.. just the dynamic content not getting added to page, also the page is very long i just posted one <p> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the error, i got the mistake in my code due to help of this post:
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969476/ajax-success-event-not-working)

I took out the datatype field and used only:

```
$("#myDiv").append(msg);
```

Now i am getting the ajax contents. AJAX is really cool, text is added as i scroll down :).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: Change your absolute `https:` URL to a relative one (such as `/kailash/cgi/testing/getdata.pl`). The only way to connect to a different domain via AJAX is with [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Another possibility: Your AJAX call is never being run. Add an `alert()` to the success call to make sure that `sendData()` is actually being called.

[Here's one example](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JFpvW/3/) of how to use `$.ajax` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure of your
$("#myDiv").append(msg.d);

, have you tried 
$("#myDiv").append(msg. responseText); ?