# using Get for ajax calls gives me 500 error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, get, webmethod

I was calling a [web method] using POST but as I am 'getting' data back I am trying to use GET instead.

Using Post works.
Using GET gives me a 500 error.

This is the main jquery call to my [web method]:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'Cloud/Feed.aspx/GetNextFrames2',
            data: '{ test: "hime"}',
```

~

This is my test [web method].

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetNextFrames2(string test)
{
    return 'test'
}
```

If I do not pass any parameters I will get no error using GET.
As soon as add a parameter I get 500 internal error.

I have used wireshark and Fiddler but I cannot see anything useful.

This is obviously down to using parameters.  So, at least I have pinpointed where the error is.

I have tried passing the parameters directly appended to the url:

myurl?par=testme...

but still same error.

What else can I try?

Thanks

Comment: 500 error is not a problem in your ajax script but in url target. if u use php I can help to solve the problem :)

Comment: Change url to full URL like http://servername/Cloud/Feed.aspx/GetNextFrames2

Comment: Look into this thread :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095041/jquery-ajax-call-for-posting-data-to-asp-net-page-not-get-but-post

Comment: @kefy IF only I was!  I found lots if google results on how to diagnose the problem IF I was using php but alas asp.net :(

Comment: @SainPradeep Hi, thanks for your suggestion.  I have tried this before but stil lno joy :(

Comment: @JananiM Hi, thanks. I did not see that 1.  I will look at this as soon as I get into work. ta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the value in the query string. The value should be within quote. The below code is working.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType:'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache:false,
            url: "TestWebMathod.aspx/GetNextFrames2?test='hime'",
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText)
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d)

            }

        });
```

Also look at the error.responseText to know the exact exception message. This will help to resolve the error.

Comment: HI, yes it does work. Thank you so much.  I need to include the ' s in the url. Superb! I am so happy

Answer (score 2):

Ajax GET requests shouldn't have Content-type since they don't have any entity-body.

For reference : [Do I need a content type for http get requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661596/do-i-need-a-content-type-for-http-get-requests)

Try

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: "Cloud/Feed.aspx/GetNextFrames2?test='hime'",
```

either of which should work

Comment: hi, rushing around for work at the mo. Thanks for your suggestion and I have tried it. I still get the same error...

Comment: The GET method doesn't have content. Any data sent via GET must sent in url

Comment: @Péter This makes a lot of sense and it what I was trying to get my head round.  The answer I accepted is based in part on your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The comments above about `contentType` for GET are correct *BUT* `WebMethods` *require it* - [see this detailed post on why](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks).

So really, unless you do `POST`, IMHO, it's just a pain to get things to work with `WebMethods`. <s>I can't even get it to work with `GET` if the method has a param (it'll bomb out), so if someone can get it to work, bravo! Note that even the link example using GET includes a param...unsure if that's simply something that *used* to be true (the date on that article is **2007**).</s>

So if you must (**updated based on answer above**):

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Cloud/Feed.aspx/GetNextFrames2",
            //data: {"test": "foo"}, // GET -> Cloud/Feed.aspx/GetNextFrames2?test=foo
            data: {"test": "'foo'"}, //value now in quotes
            ...
```

WebMethod:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string GetNextFrames2(string test)
    {
        //Should now work based on answer above

        //Yes, this is FUBAR, but technically feasible (no need for params in method)
        //var query = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;

        //now do what you need to do with your querystring data 
        // re: that's where your data is in GET ($.get)

        ....           
    }
```

Other awe-inspiring notes:

- if you have `FriendlyUrls`, you will have to comment out
  `AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent` in `RouteConfig` -> `FriendlyUrlSettings` - because it does what it says and redirect `.aspx` to a "friendly url"...yup including above...

Hope this helps and maybe get you thinking (instead) of `WebAPI` :)

---

### Update Summary

Well, the answer as shown above is to wrap `string` in quotes - so it seems to (strongly) type the parameters. So if `int`:

- if $.get data: `{ "test": 55 }`

  ```
  [WebMethod]
  [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
  public static string GetNextFrames2(int test)
  {
    ...
  ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the extra info and for that link.  You have given me things to things about and look into.  Always a good thing :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Been some for me (WebMethods), so it's a re-learning process for me too :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for summing up.  Yes, I know I normally work with Web APIs and I had always wondered why I had to include GET and POST attributes (server-side) to do a GET request from JS. Now, I think I know..