# JSON.stringify() - nested objects

Tags: ajax, json, object, stringify

What's the proper way to use JSON.stringify() on nested objects? I'm getting a bad request from a api call that expects a JSON string:

```
testData = {"credentials": {"user": "test@email.com", "password": "testpassword", "country": "us"}};
```

when I view the postDasta:

```
"{"credentials": {"user": "test@email.com", "password": "testpassword", "country": "us"}}";

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(testData),
    ...
});
```

Thanks,

J

Comment: Have you tried passing the object to the data without stringifying it?  I don't quite remember the data parameter expecting a string.  It either, as far as I remember, expects an object, or a string in lieu of a get request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was: [You need to use JSON.stringify to first serialize your object to JSON, and then specify the content-type so your server understands it's JSON.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring)

So, contentType and stringify are necessary if the server is expecting JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If this is `jQuery` (it looks like it is), the `data` parameter accepts an object and performs the necessary serialization to pass it as an associative array to the server. You don't stringify if before passing it.

Comment: if I leave off contentType:'application/json' I get: `415 Unsupported Media Type - 30ms - 752B)`. When I use a rest client the request works fine with `{"credentials": {"user": "test@email.com", "password": "testpassword", "country": "us"}}`.

Comment: @neridaj How can you expect me to respond if you don't reply on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The data parameter for jQuery's [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method does not take a json string as value.  It either expects a query-formed string(`test=value&otherstuff=othervalue`), or an object, as noted in the linked documentation above.

Comment: I removed JSON.stringify() and verified that I'm sending over an object with $.isPlainObject(testData): true. When I view the postData it looks like a url encoded querystring: "credentials%5Buser%5D=test%40email.com&credentials%5Bpassword%5D=testpassword&credentials%5B&credentials%5Bcountry%5D=us" but the contentType is set to 'application/json' and the type is set to 'post'.

Comment: `var testData = {"credentials": {"user": "test@email.com", "password": "testpassword", "country": "us"}};                        $.ajax({
                url : '/credentials', 
                type : 'post',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert('success');
                            },
                data : testData,
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('error');          
                }      
                        });`

Comment: You are not supposed to set the content type to application/json.  I don't really see a reason to use it, unless you're specifically sending over json.  As noted in the documentation, it converts any json object into a query string, so it can be converted by the server into a post request(this is done auto), eg.. without modifying the content type, it is retrievable with `$_POST`.

Comment: @neridaj You need to describe **exactly** what you are trying to achieve if you want an answer that solves your problem.  As it stands,  I have no issues executing what I told you.  No errors, etc.

Comment: Sorry for posting under the wrong response. Basically, I'm not sure why the testData works in a rest client but not when it's executed within the $.ajax() context. This only happens when testData contains a nested object.

Comment: @neridaj What context is this being done in?  What version of jQuery are you using, what framework is this in(if any), because it works fine on my end, even with the nested object.

Comment: I'm using v1.7.1 within JMVC. the request works when I add single quotes to make it a string: '{"credentials": {"user": "test@email.com", "password": "testpassword", "country": "us"}}'.

Comment: Please provide a link to the software; there are various 'JMVC's on google.