# Backbone POST JSON instead of GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

The following code works in Backbone with hardcoded data using a POST to fetch data

```
var FullTextSearch = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/fulltextsearch'
});

var SearchResultsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    var searchResults = new FullTextSearch();
    searchResults.fetch({
      type: "post",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: '{ "searchtext": "abc" }',
      success: function (searchResults) {
        var template = _.template($('#search-results-list-template').html(), {searchResults: searchResults.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Now the challenge is to pass in the data as JSON payload from a search form. I have tried something like this without success, haven't tried to load it from search form yet though that's my end goal so if there is a solution for that, it's even better!

```
<script type="text/template" id="search-results-list-template">
    <form class="search-form">
      <input type="text" name="searchtext">
      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search">
    </form>
... rest of HTML template here...
</script>

var SearchPayload = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log("SearchPayload init");
  }
});

var FullTextSearch = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/fulltextsearch'
});

var SearchResultsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',
  events: {
    'submit .search-form': 'search'
  },
  search: function(ev) {
    //This is not working yet
    var searchPayload = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
    console.log("search form clicked, " + searchText);
    return false;
  },
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    var searchResults = new FullTextSearch();
    var searchPayload = new SearchPayload({searchtext: "*"});
    searchResults.fetch({
      type: "post",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: that.searchPayload,
      success: function (searchResults) {
        var template = _.template($('#search-results-list-template').html(), {searchResults: searchResults.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

The POST request is not being set properly, here's what I am seeing in the debugger, the JSON payload is not part of the request

```
Request URL:http://localhost:1234/fulltextsearch
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Cookie: AJS.conglomerate.cookie=""
Host:localhost:1234
Origin:http://localhost:1234
Referer:http://localhost:1234/index.html?searchtext=abc
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:40
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 04 Feb 2014 23:29:46 GMT
Server:spray-can/1.2.0
```

**ANSWER**
Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring), I got it working as such

```
<script type="text/template" id="search-results-list-template">
    <form class="search-form">
      <input type="text" name="searchtext">
      <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search">
    </form>
... rest of HTML template here...
</script>

var SearchPayload = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log("SearchPayload init");
  }
});

var FullTextSearch = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/fulltextsearch'
});

var SearchResultsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.page',
  events: {
    'submit .search-form': 'search'
  },
  search: function(ev) {
    //This is not working yet
    var searchPayload = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
    console.log("search form clicked, " + searchText);
    return false;
  },
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    var searchResults = new FullTextSearch();
    var searchPayload = JSON.stringify(new SearchPayload());
    searchResults.fetch({
      type: "post",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: searchPayload,
      success: function (searchResults) {
        var template = _.template($('#search-results-list-template').html(), {searchResults: searchResults.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the source, Backbone.sync (called by fetch), uses the data from [option.attrs or the model itself](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/990ab04a459d6e240ec41ee13cbc968cdfad6130/backbone.js#L1154). Probably best to make this call on your own, outside of Backbone, and then populate the collection with results, it doesn't make sense to use fetch in this regard.

Comment: I like to keep the semantics of fetch() but as a POST and I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Backbone.emulateJSON

Comment: Actually what I needed is JSON.stringify()

Comment: aah... well glad you got the answer.

you should probably edit your question with the answer