# express body-parser middleware puts data into the property name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm new to the nodeJS Express framework. I'm consuming a POST request that I sent using the following:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var data = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.body)[0];
});
```

I've sent this data from the client via:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "write_to_region",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(grid)
});
```

where "grid" is a 2d array of values.
My express body parser is configured as follows:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false }));
```

What is a better or more idiomatic way of doing this?
Note that the array is somewhat large (10kb) and contains only integers. Ideally, I would be minimizing the amount of data sent in the request.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not setting the appropriate `Content-Type`. Jquery's default `Content-Type` for `POST`ing data is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So the body parser starts reading the request data, looking for an `=` to know when the "key" ends and the "value" starts. It never finds an `=` so it keeps appending to the key name.

To fix this you need to add these options in your `$ajax()` config:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

and add the `bodyParser.json()` middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had originally tried `contentType: "application/json"` but ran into what I now realize is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring).