# Get Multiple dropdowns value of a form and send as a query string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that have dropdowns that have multiple properties .Now on click of button i want to create array of values on the key name as the dropdown name.But i am unable to do this.
And i have to send the data of each dropdown in a query string with **ajax**

**HTML**

```
<select multiple=""  style="width: 147px;" id="list" name="list" class ="list_class">
        <option value="21">A</option>
        <option value="22">B</option>
        <option value="23">C</option>
        <option value="24">D</option>
        <option value="2">E</option>
    </select>

    <select multiple=""  style="width: 147px;" id="list1" name="list1" class ="list_class">
        <option value="22">B</option>
        <option value="24">D</option>
        <option value="2">E</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple=""  style="width: 147px;" id="list2" name="list2" class ="list_class">
        <option value="22">B</option>
        <option value="24">D</option>
        <option value="2">E</option>
    </select>
```

On button Click i am doing this to get the values :

```
$('form#add').find('select, input:text').each(function() {
            var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
            var inputValue = $(this).val();
            formData +='&'+inputName+'='+inputValue;
        });
```

I want the values in the formdata as :

```
list = ['21','22','23','24','2']
    list1 = ['23','24','2']
    list2 = ['22','24','2']
```

Comment: See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/u41pcpyu/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I create an object(`objVal`) and using [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) combine with [**.get()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) add an array with the selected values to that object(object key is the name of each select):

```js
$('#add').on("click", function() {
  var objVal = {};
  $('select').each(function() {
    var arr = $(':selected', this).map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
    objVal[$(this).attr("name")] = arr;
  });
  console.log(objVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="" style="width: 147px;" id="list" name="list" class="list_class">
  <option value="21">A</option>
  <option value="22">B</option>
  <option value="23">C</option>
  <option value="24">D</option>
  <option value="2">E</option>
</select>
<select multiple="" style="width: 147px;" id="list1" name="list1" class="list_class">
  <option value="22">B</option>
  <option value="24">D</option>
  <option value="2">E</option>
</select>
<select multiple="" style="width: 147px;" id="list2" name="list2" class="list_class">
  <option value="22">B</option>
  <option value="24">D</option>
  <option value="2">E</option>
</select>
<input type='button' id='add' />
```

Result of this example is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form#add').find('select').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var list = [];
    that.find('option').each(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('value');
        list.push(val);
    });
    return list;
});
```

Comment: i have input types also in my form .so this will not work in case on input types

Comment: @Gaurav: please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var ar = [];
$("select.list_class").each(function () {
    var obj = {};   
    obj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).children().map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    ar.push(obj);

});
console.log(ar);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u41pcpyu/1/)**

Comment: i have to send the data as a query string with ajax how could i do this ??kindly suggest

Comment: @Gaurav sorry If you need other answer ,then ask new question bcoz this ans is not useful for new visitors ,if you post new question some of users will give you great answer ....

Comment: @Gaurav see this link it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring

Comment: Kindly help me in this question i have to send the data in a query string .Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = {};

$("select option").each(function(){
    var list = $(this).parent().attr("name");
    if(list in result){
        result[list].push($(this).val());
    }else{
        result[list] = [].push($(this).val());  
    }
});

console.dir(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
var list1 = [], list2 = [], list3 = [];

var $list1 = $("#list1").find("option");
$list1.each(function () {
  var $option = $(this).attr("value");
  list1.push($option);
});

var $list2 = $("#list2").find("option");
$list2.each(function () {
  var $option = $(this).attr("value");
  list2.push($option);
});

var $list3 = $("#list3").find("option");
$list3.each(function () {
  var $option = $(this).attr("value");
  list3.push($option);
});

console.log(list1);
console.log(list2);
console.log(list3);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/wenrvj4o/)