# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net, ajax, url, post

I have a CORS Web API controller as shown below

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class AddNewLocationController : ApiController
    {
        public String Post(String param1, String param2)
        {
            return "Param1: " + param1 + ", Param2: " + param2;
        }
    }
```

I want to pass data to this controller by using Ajax. The command is successful when I add the parameters in the url:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:21626/api/AddNewLocation?param1=test1&param2=chriwil'**,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
```

When I try to pass data using the data property of the ajax call, I get the error "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"**.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:21626/api/AddNewLocation',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {param1: "param1", param2: "param2chriwil"},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not serializing the data. The second call should be

```
data: JSON.stringify({param1: "param1", param2: "param2chriwil"}),
```

See:
[jQuery ajax, how to send JSON instead of QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring)

**EDIT**

Additionally if you specify the method signature like `Post(String param1, String param2)` the engine will think that the `param1` and `param2` will come via query string - so no wonder your second invocation fails (you haven't specified the `param1` and `param2` in url); if you want to send parameter via json use this signature instead:

```
public class Model
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
}

public String Post(Model model)
{
    return "Param1: " + model.param1 + ", Param2: " + Model.param2;
}
```

Comment: I added the serializtion but I still get the same error: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:21626/api/AddLocationRating. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:46666' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to preflight response in `global.asax.cs` worked for me. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046766/2847061