# Angularjs $http.post - sending params as JSON to ASPX webmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, webmethod

I have the following angularjs code sending http post to a webmethod, but I get the following error with no more info. Can someone help? 
If I do not send any data to webmethod and only get data from it, it works just fine !

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
angular.js:11442 POST http://localhost:54461/GetData.aspx/getData 500 (Internal Server Error)

Javascript:

```
var request = "{'name':'" + "Nariman" + "'age':'" + 12 + "'}";
$scope.retData = {};

var config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': '"application/json; charset=utf-8";',
        'dataType': '"json"'
    }
}

$scope.retData.getResult = function (item, event) {

    $http.post('GetData.aspx/getData', request, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.retData.result = data.d;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });
}
```

ASPX webmethod (C#):

```
public static string getData(string name, int age)
{
    string.Format("Name: {0}{2}Age: {1}", name, age, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

**EDIT** --------------------------------------

If I do not send any json data to the webmethod, it works just fine. for example the below code works and if I put break point inside the webmethod, it shows that it goes there. but if I send json data, it does not go inside webmethod:

Javaacript (not sending any json data):

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': '"application/json; charset=utf-8";',
        'dataType': '"json"'
    }
}

$scope.retData.getResult = function(item, event) {
    $http.post('GetData.aspx/getData', data, config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.retData.result = data.d;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });
}
```

ASPX (When no input param)

```
public static string getData()
{
    // just having a breakpoint shows it comes inside the 
    // webmethod when no data is passed. 
}
```

Comment: Can you try var `request = JSON.stringify({name: "Nariman", age:12});`

Comment: error code `500` means you got some exception on your server side code. I would suggest you should have a look there for exceptions. As you pointed about data being passed from client, it most probably looks like some unexpected value on server. You can get more details about that from server exception.

Comment: @EmmanuelDurai thanks. I just tried now...still the same error.

Comment: @S4beR thanks for the reply. its a local host (Visual Studio Debug mode)...and it does not fail on my server side code at all ! If I do not pass any data and only make a call to getdata, it works just one. but with passing data, it does not even go to my webmethod when I put a break point there.

Comment: is it possible for you to share the format of data passed from client to server in API call and how are you reading it on server?

Comment: @S4beR the format from client to server is json, and in webmethod I want to read them as function input params and not query string !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your issue seems to be as pointed by Emmanual Durai in first comment of your question: `var request = "{'name':'" + "Nariman" + "'age':'" + 12 + "'}";` is not a valid json object.

**request** will give you `{'name':'Nariman'age':'12'}` as String which won't parse to JSON (there are issues with format).

You should try something like below to get a valid string

```
var request = {
    name: "Nariman",
    age: 12
}

var requestString = JSON.stringify(request)
```

also please have a look here [How to pass json POST data to Web API method as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object). your issue is not typically specific to angularjs `$http` but in general to `XHR` request.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what should I do if I want to send an obj as json?  Does something like :  var obj = {};
        obj.name ="nariman"
        obj.age = 12      works?  I tried and its not workin?!!!

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring

Answer (score 2):

Simply change:

```
var request = "{'name':'" + "Nariman" + "'age':'" + 12 + "'}";
```

To:

```
var request = { name: "Nariman", age: 12 };
```

You don't have to use JSON.stringify()

```
var request = { name: "Nariman", age: 12 };
var config = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
}
    $http.post('GetData.aspx/getData', request, config)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.retData.result = data.d;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what should I do if I want to send an obj as json? Does something like : var obj = {}; obj.name ="nariman" obj.age = 12 works? I tried and its not workin?!!!

Comment: thanks but your solution does not work if I do not use  JSON.stringify()