# Poison seems to automatically convert a JSON array of objects to a map. What can I do to prevent that?

Tags: json, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison

In my app I accept a JSON object at one of the API endpoints:

```
pipeline :api do
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
end
```

Within this JSON object, there is an array of objects, e.g. the structure might be like this:

```
{
  "a": "...",
  "b": [{"c": "...", "d": "..."}, {"c": "...", "d": "..."}]
}
```

In my controller, when I try to access the array of objects with `params["b"]`, I'm surprised to find that I get a map, with the index being the original indices of the array, but in string form!

This means it's practically impossible for me to recover the original ordering of `b`, since the order of map traversal is not guaranteed to be preserved in Elixir.

The only thing I can do seems to be to convert the **string** indices back into their original integer form, and then convert the map into a list, before sorting the list, which is a lot of hassle for no apparent reason.

However, when I have a simple JSON array, e.g.

```
{
  "a": "...",
  "b": ["itemA", "itemB"]
}
```

then `params["b"]` in my controller indeed gives me an Elixir list, which has its order preserved and is exactly what I want.

Why did this happen? Is there anything I can do to preserve the original order of the objects in that array?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. JSON you have posted is successfully decoded to an array. Please post a real data you experience the issues with.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for the comment. I investigated further and turns out I wasn't sending the data correctly in the first place. the Content-Type was specified as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. It should be changed to `application/json` and the data should be `JSON.stringify(data)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't sending the data correctly in the first place. the Content-Type was specified as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. It should be changed to `application/json` and the data should be `JSON.stringify(data)` instead. See [jQuery ajax, how to send JSON instead of QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/jquery-ajax-how-to-send-json-instead-of-querystring).