# jQuery : How to send JSON data in AJAX post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, content-type

I am working on AJAX. I create a post request like the following :

```
   $.ajax({
    'url':'http://localhost/api/create/',
    'method':'POST',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'data':{
        "refId":585,
        "phone":"0674444444"
     },
     'success': getHandlingStatus

  });
```

When my request is executed, data are passed as parameters in my request payload and not as JSON data.
Here is my Request Payload:

```
refId=585&phone=0674444444
```

I want to send data in json format like :

```
{
"refId":"585",
"phone:"0674444444"
}
```

What am I missing please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send JSON instead of a query string with $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/how-to-send-json-instead-of-a-query-string-with-ajax)

Answer (score 17):

You need to use JSON.stringify to convert data to JSON along with ProcessData option set to false. 
As per documentation of jquery:

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

```
$.ajax({
'url':'http://localhost/api/create/',
'method':'POST',
'dataType': 'json',
 processData: false,
'contentType': 'application/json',
'data':JSON.stringify({
    "refId":585,
    "phone":"0674444444"
 }),
 'success': getHandlingStatus

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the data to `JSON` format. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
 $.ajax({
'url':'http://localhost/api/create/',
'method':'POST',
'dataType': 'json',
'contentType': 'application/json',
'data':JSON.stringify({
    "refId":585,
    "phone":"0674444444"
 }),
 'success': getHandlingStatus
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Have you tried the following
```

```
    $.ajax({
        'url':'http://localhost/api/create/',
        'method':'POST',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'data': JSON.stringify({
            "refId":585,
            "phone":"0674444444"
         }),
         'processData': false,
         'success': getHandlingStatus

      });
```

*There was a comma missing after processData: false*