# How to pass ajax post data to nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, ejs

So I'm making an API call and one of the objects within that call is a unique ID. I'm trying to pass that ID object back server side using Ajax. It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my client side code, first I loop through a javascript object:

```
<% apiResultsdata['items'].forEach(function(items) { %>

    <% let ID = items['id'] %>
    <% let volumeInfo = items['volumeInfo'] %>
    <% let author = volumeInfo['authors'] %>
    <% let title = volumeInfo['title'] %>
    <% let image = null %>
    <% if(!(volumeInfo['imageLinks'] === undefined)) { %>
      <% image = volumeInfo['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'] %>
 <% } %>
```

ID is what I need to pass back to nodejs after a link is clicked:

```
<div class="col">
                <div class="card-block px-2">
                  <a  href="/bookDetails"><h5 class="card-title"><%= title %></h5></a>


                  <script type="text/javascript">
                      $('a').click(function() {
                        $.ajax({
                          type: 'post',
                          data: {'ID':'<%= ID %>'},
                          url: 'localhost:3000/bookDetails',
                          success: function(data){
                            console.log('success');
                          }
                        });
                      });
                  </script>
```

In my data filed, I'm passing ID as a ejs object because that's the templating language I'm using. Not sure if that's right.

Here is the post route on the server:

```
router.post('/bookDetails', (req, res) => {
  let ID = req.query.ID;
  console.log('ID: ' + ID);
});
```

Comment: try adding `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call, by default it treats it as form data.

Comment: @AdamH that didn't work either but thanks.

Comment: `req.query.ID` is pulling from the query string, user `req.body.ID` that will pull from both, sorry I didn't see that the first time.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Comment: @AdamH still nothing. Do you think I'm padding my data the right way in ajax and do I need localhost for url?

Comment: You should look at the answer below, that's is most likely your issue. You will need the body parser that is referenced too and then you would use req.body.ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `contentType` and `JSON.stringify` the object before passing to the data field. ([check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/how-to-send-json-instead-of-a-query-string-with-ajax))

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ ID: '<%= ID %>' }),
    url: 'localhost:3000/bookDetails',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

And it's always a good idea to use a json-parser middleware on the server side

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then you can get the request body that contains the `ID` parameter as follows

```js
router.post('/bookDetails', (req, res) => {
  let ID = req.body.ID;
  console.log('ID: ' + ID);
});
```

Comment: thanks. For some reason, it still doesn't work. After sitting up body-parser this is how I'm using it in my post route:  'let ID = req.body'    you think this is right?

Comment: `req.body` is the object that contains the `ID` field. Try `req.body.ID` instead. `let ID = req.body.ID`