# What's the best way to let JQuery ajax post JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, flask

I have a HTTP server built using Python Flask, which serves an API as a backend, and a webpage which calls the API using JQuery ajax. When I make a POST request, I got some parsing problem on the server site. My JQuery POST looks like the following.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "<API endpoint, on same server>",
  data: <a javascript object>, //yes, this is the cause of the problem
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json"

}).done(func_success).fail(func_error);
```

Notice that the `data` field was given a javascript object. At first I thought if I specified `contentType` to be `application/json`, the `ajax` function will make the `data` into a JSON format. However, a simple print on the server revealed it was not the case. The `contentType` field is only responsible to set the `Content-Type` header. By default, JQuery always converts a plain javacript object to `url-encoded` format, regardless of the `dataType` parameter given.

As a walkaround, I used `JSON.stringify(data)` to serialize the javascript object to a JSON string. However, I wonder whether there is a better practice to use `ajax` function. If you are to POST a javascript in JSON format using JQuery, how would you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send JSON instead of a query string with $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/how-to-send-json-instead-of-a-query-string-with-ajax)

Comment: @NickK9 Hi Nick. Thanks for making the reference. I understand that `stringify` can be a solution. I'm also aware that there's an option in `ajax` function called `converters`. If I insist on providing a javascript object to `data` instead of the stringified JSON, can I make use of this `converters` field? My intuition is I can use it to convert my data, but I didn't see any documentation about it.