# Express POST command having problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I am using express and am trying to run a **POST** command code :

***HTML and JS Code:***

```
    <body>
    <h1>this is the survey page</h1>

    <a href="/api/users">USERS</a>

    <form method="POST" role="form">
        <input id="name" placeholder="name">
        <input id="pic" placeholder="pic">
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").on("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        // event.preventDefault();

        var newUser = {
            name: $("#name").val().trim(),
            profile_pic: $("#pic").val().trim(),
            scores: [
                5,
                1,
                4,
                4,
                5,
                1,
                2,
                5,
                4,
                1
            ]
        }

        $.post("/api/users", newUser, 
            function(data){
                if(data){
                    console.log("you completed the survey")
                }
                else{
                    console.log("error");
                }
            }
        );
    })
```

Express Code :

**SERVER:**

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

require("./routing/apiRoutes")(app);
require("./routing/htmlRoutes")(app);

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("App listening on PORT: " + PORT);
});
```

**apiRoutes**

```
var userData = require("../data/friends");

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get("/api/users", function(req, res){
        res.json(userData);
    });

    app.post("/api/users"), function(req, res){
        userData.push(req.body);
        res.json(true);
    }
}
```

**HTML ROUTES**

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get("/survey", function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/survey.html"));
    })

    app.get("*", function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../public/home.html"));
    })
}
```

Whenever I run click the submit button it should run the post but I get the following error:

jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8080/api/users 404 (Not Found)

I'm not really sure how to resole this issue, any thoughts?

Comment: What do your `htmlRoutes` look like?

Comment: I think the issue might be your use of `express.urlencoded({ extended: false })` and the type of data you're posting. Your `scores` array would need `extended` processing... [_"The “extended” syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format"_](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded). That being said, I strongly suggest posting your data as JSON instead. See [How to send JSON instead of a query string with $.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693986/283366)

Comment: I just updated the question with my htmlRoutes code, pretty simple stuff in that file

Comment: You have a typo in `apiRoutes` (missing `)` for the `app.post()`). Is that typo in your actual code?

Comment: @Phil wow... that was It... feel like an idiot...