I need to decode $_POST so I can see what my javascript is actually sending to my php probram
I am using jquery datatables and I want to send a date to the php code to use in my parametrized query  Here is my datatables ajax entry:
  ajax: {
        url: "php/stopCodes.php",
        data: JSON.stringify( {stopCodeDate : $('#stopCodeDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val() }),
        type: "POST",
        dataSrc: ""
       


    },

I have this code in my php:
$postData =  file_get_contents('php://input');
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($postData);

network tools payLoad (parsed) shows:
{"stopCodeDate":"05/30/2024"}
which looks like good json to me.
But when I execute:
    $param =file_get_contents("php://input");
;

$paramValue = json_decode($param,false);


$stopCodeDate =  $paramValue->{"stopCodeDate"};

I get the following message: Warning: Attempt to read property "stopCodeDate" on null
echo ("param="+$param); 

yeilds 'unparsed/source' value from networ/payload.
If i hard-code $param:
$param = '{"stopCodeDate": "05/30/2024"}';

The code works as expected.


If you want to see what your browser code is sending to the server, you can use the Network tool in your browser (click on the relevant request and inspect its Payload). 2) In PHP, why not inspect $_POST, where PHP should have already parsed this data? Reading the raw input isn't necessary, unless for example you're sending data in JSON format, which it seems you aren't in this case.


My mistake on the php version.  I am using php8.
As I am using datatables, I am sending JSON.  The output is from the network tool in Edge

htmlspecialchars_decode should not be used. Provide raw output please without any functions applied.

ADyson:  Thank you.  I was looking at the wrong part of the network tool (preview).  The payload section has what I am looking for.

I am sending JSON...not really. PHP won't necessarily see it like that, unless you set the right Content-Type header in the request as well.  And you shouldn't ever build JSON by hand like that, it's prone to unexpected syntax errors. Instead make an object literal in JS and then use JSON.stringify to reliably convert it

And then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php for how to deal with it properly in PHP. JSON isn't HTML, so htmlspecialchars isn't relevant.

"I am sending JSON" What you showed in the question is not JSON.

And yes it's also not compliant as JSON due to missing quote marks round the property name, single quotes round the value, and the spaces either side. JSON isn't as lenient as JS object literals. So...another reason to use JSON.stringify, then you don't needlessly run into these kinds of mistakes.

Thanks for editing. You can check whether a string is valid JSON or not by putting it into a site like https://jsonlint.com/ . The string you've quoted and are saying "that looks like valid JSON to me" absolutely is not valid JSON, at all. And if you've ever actually seen any valid JSON, you'd notice pretty quickly that it's not JSON, without even needing to validate it.

TBH I can't see how you could possibly have ended up with that as your payload either, it just looks like it's taken the data as a literal value and then somehow mangled each character into separate properties. Still no clue how it got like that though, from the code provided. Did you check the Content-Type header in the Request headers of that request? Did you set a content-type header in your JS code, as I advised previously? I'm guessing whatever AJAX client you're using hasn't interpreted the data as JSON.

You need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693947/how-to-send-json-instead-of-a-query-string-with-ajax (because AFAIK DataTables uses jQuery $.ajax as its AJAX client)

You should be writing ajax: {         url: "php/stopCodes.php",         data: JSON.stringify( {stopCodeDate : $('#stopCodeDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val() }),         type: "POST", contentType: "application/json" in your DataTables options, I think. Then you can proceed as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php on the PHP side.

Please see my latest edit (5/30/2024; 7:29pm EDT)

I was able to resolve this as follows
using the information in the following post:
StackOverflow: Send JSON from JavaScript to PHP
I used the following javascript code:
 ajax: {


url: "php/stopCodes.php",
        data: { json: JSON.stringify( {stopCodeDate : $('#stopCodeDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val() }) },
        type: "POST",
        dataSrc: ""
 }

and in my php:
 $parameters = json_decode($_POST["json"],true);
$stopCodeDate =  $parameters["stopCodeDate"];

The fact that this works, suggests to me that I was on the wrong track. What I have done here is send the json as a single urlencoded string parameter named 'json'. A much simpler solution which I have tested and works for me is:
javascript:
  ajax: {
    
    url: "php/stopCodes.php",
    data: {stopCodeDate: $('#stopCodeDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val() },
    type: "POST",
    dataSrc: ""

   


},

and php:
  $stopCodeDate = $_POST["stopCodeDate"];

