# jQuery UI not autocompleting from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When I look the response from Chrome Developer Tools I see this:

```
[{
"summary": "foo",
"key": "myKey"
}]
```

My javascript(UPDATED):

```
jquery183(function() { 
jquery183( "#city" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        jquery183.ajax({
            url: '/servlet/ajax/',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( jquery183.map( data, function( issue ) {
                    return {
                        label: issue.summary + ", " + issue.key,
                        value: issue.summary
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    open: function() {
        jquery183( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        jquery183( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
});
```

});

HTML:

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="city">Your city: </label>
    <input id="city" />
    Powered by <a href="http://geonames.org">geonames.org</a>
 </div>
```

I thought this should work, but it does not suggest any autocomplete items. Any suggestions?

If more code needed, feel free to ask.

Comment: There is no `success` option in the autocomplete widget. Chances are you're looking for the [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option instead.

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi : I took the example from here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp .. There is `success`.

Comment: the `success` option applies to the surrounding ajax call, *not* to the autocomplete function.

Comment: So what I am doing wrong? I put the whole code up, I think it applies to ajax at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer from here:

[Ajax success event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969476/ajax-success-event-not-working)

> The result is probably not in JSON format, so when jQuery tries to parse it as such, it fails. You can catch the error with error: callback function.
>
> You don't seem to need JSON in that function anyways, so you can also
>   take out the dataType: 'json' row.

Answer (score 1):

As seen on: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

You forgot to copy/paste the ajax call to retrieve your data.

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                value: item.name
              }
            }));
          }
        });
      }
});
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt paste whole code, i put it all up now. i got ajax there

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but is there a problem with `<input id="city" />`. It should probably be `<input id="city" type="text"/>`