# Success function not executing in ajax while using ashx hanler

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am uploading data and image using ashx handler , they are working fine.

But my success function in ajax is not getting executed

See here:

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Scripts/uploadify/UploadHandler.ashx",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: imag,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data.bb);
                    alert('hii');
                }

            });
```

Ashx:

```
       public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

        {
           HttpPostedFile PostedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
        if (!(PostedFile == null))
         {
           |
           | 
          }
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string bb = PostedFile.FileName;
            context.Response.Write(bb); //im getting bb name correctly suppose 'koyla.jpg'
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
         get
           {
        return false;
            }
        }
```

Im not getting bb in success function , alert is not even executing..???

**Update:**

```
       var fileUpload = $("#image").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;

            var imag = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                imag.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                imag.append('Data',JSON.stringify({ objEnt: args }));

            }
```

Comment: url should be ../Scripts/uploadify/UploadHandler.ashx/ProcessRequest

Comment: Are you sure data is imag ? data: imag,

Comment: Clink ya!! Correct data

Comment: @user3640046 can you show us the imag ??

Comment: @Anoop saving image and data working fine..but the problem is wit response which handler is returning not getting in ajax success

Comment: Instead of returning void, can you return any bool value?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969476/ajax-success-event-not-working - does your ashx return a valid json response?

Comment: @Dave even if i change contenttype to text/plain and return a string value , still it is not getting response in ajax success

Comment: What does the response look like in the network tab of your favourite browser developer tools?

Comment: Its nothing showing on response..but if i put the  error: functioni(data){alert('dd' }  then alert is coming..

Comment: response is always nothing!!!!no null, no "", no value...simply nothing