# Ajax call not getting a success response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response

We have 2 text fields. We have tried to post user_Name and Password  through an ajax call.

We have used PHP services and the username and password do save to the DB successfully.

But we do not get any response from our success or fail.

The code:

PHP:

```
 if(isset($_GET['ecovauserName']) && isset($_GET['ecovauserage']) ){
    $ecovauserName             = $_GET['ecovauserName'];
    $ecovauserage              = $_GET['ecovauserage'];



     $sql  = "SELECT ecovauserName,ecovauserage FROM ecovauserinfo WHERE ecovauserName = '" . $ecovauserName . "' and ecovauserage = '" . $ecovauserage . "'";
    $query      = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        echo "fail to post";
    }
    else
        {  echo("Entered into DB inserting the values");

        $insert = "INSERT INTO ecovauserinfo (ecovauserName,ecovauserage)
                        VALUES ('" . $ecovauserName . "','" . $ecovauserage . "')";

        $query  = mysql_query($insert);
        echo $insert;
        if ($query)
        {
            echo "EventFile Successfully stored";
        }
            else
            {


                echo "Insert failed";
            }
        }
     }
```

Ajax Call:-

```
 $.ajax({
               url:'http://192.168.3.134:8080/ekova/postevent.php',
               type:'POST',
               data:{ecovauserName :username,ecovauserage:password},
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
               success:function(responsive){
                alert(responsive);
               },
               error:function(w,t,f){
                 console.log(w+' '+t+' '+f);
               }
            });
```

The above code is working fine. The username and password are successfully stored in the DB. But we need to get a success of fail response.

My success:function is not called and so my alert box never runs to notify me of the success.

Please guide me with what is wrong in the code.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1):

The data type should read "json" not "jsonp"

I would suggest that you use "text" instead of "json" since you are returning  normal text results and not json encoded data.

Comment: thanks for reply.We tried as you said but when we placed JSON ,data Not saved in DB

Comment: the dataType is used to tell ajax what data is expected to RETURN and not SEND. So this change should not have affected anything in your posting/saving. Also NOTE> you are telling AJAX to POST but you are checking the $_GET globals. You will need to use $_POST['ecovauserName'] and $_POST['ecovauserage']

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing the line dataType: "jsonp" - that's had some success.

See this post: [Ajax success event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969476/ajax-success-event-not-working)

EDIT - try putting basic console.log statements in both success and fail just to see if either are being hit.

```
$.ajax({
           url:'http://192.168.3.134:8080/ekova/postevent.php',
           type:'POST',
           data:{ecovauserName :username,ecovauserage:password},
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
           success:function(){
            console.log('in success');
           },
           error:function(){
             console.log('in error');
           }
        });
```

Check whether you're getting an error:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var error1 = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  console.log(error1.Message);
  console.log(geturl.getAllResponseHeaders());
  alert("error!"+ geturl.getAllResponseHeaders());
}
```

Comment: we tried remove jsonp.but success method not calling

Comment: If you put a console.log("blablabla") into success and fail are either of those called? - answer edited to reflect.

Comment: in success function console.log not called but values stored in db please guide me how call success

Comment: Can you try changing the dataType to "text"? And also put into the success as well as the console.log the following:  return alert("Testing");

Comment: we placed case1) dataType:Text we get 'in fail',case2)dataType:json we get 'in fail' case3) dataType:jsonp we get 'in fail' but only case3 data save to DB

Comment: Could be your headers - you need to print out the error your getting to the console log. Answer edited.

Comment: we print console.log(error1.Message);
we got this 
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Message' of undefined and alert is not work

Comment: Ok definitely think its your headers - put this at the top of your PHP file underneath the first <?php tag -  header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: we got error this
 [object Object] parsererror Error: jQuery111002164177882950753_1425642125857 was not called

Comment: Moved these messages to chat.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use status codes returned by the call, as an example:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'http://192.168.3.134:8080/ekova/postevent.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:{ecovauserName :username,ecovauserage:password},
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  statusCode: {
    404: function () {
      //error
    },
    200: function (data) {
      //response data
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a `json_encode` response in your php call, like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'in success'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems doing a query with cross-domain and jsonp make that possible.

So, in your php code you have to return a jsonp format :

```
$response = array('success' => false, 'message' => '');

if (isset($_GET['ecovauserName']) && isset($_GET['ecovauserage'])) {
    $ecovauserName = $_GET['ecovauserName'];
    $ecovauserage = $_GET['ecovauserage'];

    $sql = "SELECT ecovauserName,ecovauserage FROM ecovauserinfo WHERE ecovauserName = '" . $ecovauserName . "' and ecovauserage = '" . $ecovauserage . "'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $response['message'] = 'fail to post';
    } else {
        $insert = "INSERT INTO ecovauserinfo (ecovauserName,ecovauserage) VALUES ('" . $ecovauserName . "','" . $ecovauserage . "')";

        $query = mysql_query($insert);
        if ($query) {
            $response['message'] = 'EventFile Successfully stored';
            $response['success'] = true;
        } else {
            $response['message'] = 'Insert failed';
        }
    }
}
// The header is for telling that you are sending a json response
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

// formatting a response as jsonp format.
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($response) . ')';
```

In your javascript :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.3.134:8080/ekova/postevent.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {ecovauserName: username, ecovauserage: password},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.message);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

More information at http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp

Comment: thanks for reply we are new to PHP please explain where we placed two lines 
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($response) . ')';

Comment: we got 
 error: function() {
        console.log('error');
    }
error

Comment: add for debug `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }`

Comment: we got errors this
 Object
 parsererror
 Error: jQuery111002985340391751379_1425647499106 was not called
file:///D:/SaveApp/SaveApp/assets/ForLL/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.map Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND