# Set delay between some echo via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, delay

So I have html form send data via ajax to php like:

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var ajaxname=$("#name").val();
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"some.php",
            data:"name="+ajaxname,
            success:function(data){
                $("#formresult").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input id="button" type="button" value="send"/>
</form>
<div id="formresult"></div>
```

and php file like:

some.php

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];

if($name == "mahdi"){
    echo 'true' . '<br/>';
    echo 'welcome' . '<br/>';
    echo 'have good time!' . '<br/>';
}
else{
    echo 'false' . '<br/>';
    echo 'wrong name' . '<br/>';
}

?>
```

When form submit and AJAX callback success, show all of echo in one moment and together. but I want echo "**delay in time**" for example 2 sec between any echo.

I used "*sleep(2);*" in php, "*setTimeout*" and "*for loop*" in JavaScript, but no one does not work.

Please anybody know the answer put it in https://jsfiddle.net/ to see it work.

Comment: Change your AJAX response to a structured format such as JSON. Then output each part of response by delay using setTimeout.

Comment: @Tasos it working only for show some sentences without connect to php file and do process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of confusion here. If I understand correctly, you want each of the echos to execute with a 2 second delay between them, resulting in the text of each echo displaying one after another on the page?

If so, you can't use one PHP script with a set of echos like that. You'd need to send back an array of strings and have JavaScript use setInterval to display one at a time.

Edit for example:

PHP would be something like:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$name = $_POST['name'];

if($name == "mahdi"){
    echo json_encode(array('true', 'welcome', 'have good time!'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('false', 'wrong name'));
}
```

And JS like:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var ajaxname = $("#name").val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "name=" + ajaxname,
        success: function (data) {
            var index = 0;
            var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                $("#formresult").append('<p>' + data[index] + '</p>');
                index = index + 1;
                if (index === data.length) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

This sets a setInterval after successful AJAX response. After all messages are appended to #formresult, the interval is cleared.

Comment: could you make a example please?

Comment: oh its work and really cool but have you seen it? all letters of words become separate in result. for example 'true' or 'welcome' become t r u e and w e l c o m e . why?!

Comment: Updated example :) now it is set to JSON data type.

Answer (score 0):

when you use Ajax, the request sent to server and waits to server do the job and return the response.you can not get the result in separated parts.

you have to use Socket to do such things.

Comment: This is definitely not an answer.

Comment: he wants to get the data chunk by chunk.can you do it with Ajax?

Comment: Yes, I can receive all data and output it via `setTimeout`.

Comment: definitely  you do not understand the question.he has a request.not different queries.

Answer (score 0):

To make it delay in PHP do:

```
<?php
sleep(1);
$name=$_POST['name'];

if($name == "mahdi"){

echo 'true' . '<br/>';

echo 'welcome' . '<br/>';

echo 'have good time!' . '<br/>';
}
else{
echo 'false' . '<br/>';
echo 'wrong name' . '<br/>';
}

?>
```

But for Javascript use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#button").click(function(){

var ajaxname=$("#name").val();
   $.ajax({
          method:"POST",
          url:"some.php",
          data:"name="+ajaxname,
          success:function(data){setTimeout(function(data){
                          $("#formresult").html(data);

                                }});
                          },2000,data)};
</script>

<form>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input id="button" type="button" value="send"/>
</form>
 <div id="formresult"></div>
```

Keep in mind, by using both snippets you will get a total of a 4 second delay.

Comment: No need to use `sleep(1)`, just add `1000` to `setTimeout`)

Comment: That's in the second example

Comment: no it make delay for "n" sec and echo all of statements all together not one by one and delay

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this. You can use `setTimeout`.

https://jsfiddle.net/687qgqz0/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=687qgqz0

Comment: nope! it make delay for "n" sec and echo all of statements all together not one by one and delay

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array from `php`, iterate returned array with `$.each()`, use `.delay()`, `.queue()`, at `success` to delay two seconds between each call to `.append()`

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <input id="button" type="button" value="send" />
</form>
<div id="formresult"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var arr = ["true<br/>"
            , "welcome<br/>"
            , "have good time!<br>"
            , "false<br/>"
            , "wrong name<br>"];
  $("#button").click(function() {

    var ajaxname = $("#name").val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/echo/json/",
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify(arr)
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, html) {
            $("#formresult").delay(2000)
            .queue(function(next) {
              $("#formresult").append(html);
              next()
            })
        })
      }
    });
  })

</script>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/berhth9r/

Comment: please, more explain for me. should I change that php code too?

Comment: but I think you are sending "arr" data with "json" type via "AJAX". So where you use value of input name and send it?

Comment: @mahdi `arr` at Answer is to demonstrate approach at jsfiddle, which `echo`s posted data, see http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html. Use `data:{name:ajaxname}` or `data:"name="+ajaxname` at actual `javascript`

Comment: yeah i do. in console inspect element it "POST 200 OK" and in Response show the result but page is blank yet

Comment: @mahdi _"and in Response show the result but page is blank yet"_ After two seconds? What does `console.log(data)` log within `success` callback?

Comment: I don't know after two second or not because there isn't any result on page but on the console in "Response" tell {true<br/>welcome<br/>have good time!<br/>} and in "HTML" tell {true
welcome
have good time!}

Comment: Is an object or an array returned as `data`? Are you stating that the entire string is appended to `document`?

Comment: @mahdi _"nope! today it made really confused!"_ ?

Comment: I told no,  there isn't any an object or an array returned as data. I don't know why it doesn't work and I confused

Comment: `console.log(data)` does not log any value at `console`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1969520/6838666 problem was this and I fix it. So now I have echo but still there is no "delay"

Comment: _"but still there is no "delay""_ What do you mean? Is the array returned as `data` at `success`?

Comment: I exactly copy code you write in here and php file is up there.  Is the array returned as data at success?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` within `success` log at `console`?

Comment: NOTING look=> http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00823/rabzwkucz9g1.jpg http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00823/pshgyy56wwoz.jpg

Comment: When you include `console.log(data)` within `success` function, what is logged at `console`? Did you click button?

Comment: yes I clicked but noting logged as you see in photos

Comment: The image does not help. Are you aware of what `console` is? See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference?hl=en#log. Press `F12` key, click button and share what, if anything, is printed.

Comment: if i insert dataType: "json",in source console is blank even I click button. but if I remove it and click button error me: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj

Comment: Have you returned valid `JSON` from `php`?

Answer (score -1):

use below code

```
<?php

     $name="mahdi";

     if($name == "mahdi"){

     echo 'true' . '<br/>';
     sleep(2);
     echo 'welcome' . '<br/>';
     sleep(2);
     echo 'have good time!' . '<br/>';
     }
     else{
     echo 'false' . '<br/>';
     echo 'wrong name' . '<br/>';
     }

     ?>
```

Comment: Learn some web-basics or check if you really get your output with delay.