# jquery $.ajax success not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

for some reason  my $.ajax() is posting  but not providing a success message  which is rather strange because i am using the same code from another application just with different values

```
$("#submit").click(function(e)
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#email_address").val();
    var url = "<?=base_url()?>" + "account/validate_registration";
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        data:{"email_address":email},
        success: function(res,status){
            alert(res);
        }
    });
});
```

Sometimes chrome developer console  displays the response of the php file which is

```
print_r($_POST);
```

I cant understand how it works in one application and not in this one

Comment: Does the request show that it returned successfully in the developer tools network tab?

Comment: I would advise you to include `error: function(response){alert(response);}` as well to make sure that the ajax returns success, and not error. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yet what is the actual error that you getting from the ajax call?

Comment: I'm ok with Ivanov you should add the error part with `console.log(response);` to have better idea of what's not working. And where is your problem? You don't go to the success part of your ajax call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax success event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969476/ajax-success-event-not-working)

Comment: try only success: function(res){

Comment: sometimes the response in the network tab prints of the post sometimes it doesnt  there's times i see it posting but then times i see it has'nt its strange i will try console.log see what that sends

Comment: i rewrote it and put the error: in and it worked however when i removed the error: it still worked so i'm going to investigate where the typo was thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        dataType: "json", 
        data:{"email_address":email},
        success: function(res,status){
            alert(res);
        }
    });



this url should return json data (var url = "<?=base_url()?>" + "account/validate_registration";)
```