# Firefox developer tools truncates long network response, Chrome does not show

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I used (winter 2018) to be able to capture a JSON response using either
Chrome or Firefox developer tools. Now for the long ones I need (`>> 1 MB`) Chrome doesn't work, and Firefox truncates at 1 megabyte. This was using the developer tools. Short ones work on Firefox.

There was a recent response on "firebug" saying it was fixed in Firefox, but no. 
This was a response from familytreedna.com of a big JSON file used to construct a tree. The web page works ... but it takes a long time to download the data file (11 megabytes!) Is this a bug or "feature" in the developer tools.

Comment: Please add a [mcve], including an illustration of the problem. The cause may be in the way you handle the data or in the way you interact with a server, or in your server logic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939126/how-to-debug-ajax-response may help to find out if the response is really truncated in the runtime, or it's just the devtools UI not showing it all.

Answer (score 142):

Firefox dev tools network inspector still truncates responses to 1MB by default.

You can change or disable the limit by navigating to `about:config` and changing `devtools.netmonitor.responseBodyLimit`. To disable the limit, set it to 0.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible `devtools.netmonitor.responseBodyLimit` does not apply to WebSocket frames in the WS Inspector?

Comment: For WS I believe it is `devtools.netmonitor.ws.messageDataLimit` https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1565226

Comment: is there a similar thing in chrome? it seems to also truncate without warning. it just shows nothing when large

Comment: This works, but it's very slow. I'm not sure why its fast to write a large object to the console, but slow to view it in the network tab.

Comment: works perfectly after setting it to 0 thanks a lot!

Comment: `devtools.netmonitor.requestBodyLimit` just to mention if your request is also huge. But 0 doesn't work for me in DevTools and it is still truncated.
Copy as Curl rules.

Comment: Figured I'd say this because it might save somebody a couple of seconds: when you change the setting to 0, the "Response has been truncated" immediately disappears, but Firefox will still be rendering the truncated response *until you refresh the tab.*

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

See @Joni's answer for more info about it.

**Original Answer**

This bug already [reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1223726) on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org and fixed in Firefox 61.

So update your browser to v61 (*if you didn't already*) and feel free to report the issue on bugzilla if it's still exists.

Comment: As of Firefox 73, responses are still truncated to 1mb by default. The "fix" was to add a user preference to remove this limit. So Joni's answer is more useful here.

Comment: This is still happening in 109. (latest version today)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, about:config and changing devtools.netmonitor.responseBodyLimit to 0 fixed the issue for me in which I could not copy much text at all, but now can copy well over 1,000 words, though sometimes the browser will crash (not for lack of system memory though).