# Chrome developer tools truncates long network response

Tags: developer-tools, google-developers-console

Is there a similar fix for chrome as the one proposed by jon in this post 4 years ago :

[Firefox developer tools truncates long network response, Chrome does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687462/firefox-developer-tools-truncates-long-network-response-chrome-does-not-show#new-answer?newreg=35c2c0a3a21540cc868775e12478de20)

thank you

tried this fix for firefox : [Firefox developer tools truncates long network response, Chrome does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687462/firefox-developer-tools-truncates-long-network-response-chrome-does-not-show#new-answer?newreg=35c2c0a3a21540cc868775e12478de20)

worked but  trying to find the same for chrome