# MVC RedirectToAction Doesn't Work After JSON Post Return

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to change the page after post process of the AJAX process which executes by MVC. I have used it different way maybe my usage might be wrong.

C# MVC code part. I am sending int list which is user list and process and do something.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectUserPost(int[] usersListArray)
{
    // lots of code but omitted

    return JavaScript("window.location = '" + Url.Action("Index", "Courses") + "'"); // this does not work
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); // this also does not            
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Courses"); // this also does not
}
```

My problem is redirect part do not work after the MVC process ends. Process works, only redirect doesn't.

JavaScript code here

```
// Handle form submission event
$('#mySubmit').on('click',
    function(e) {
        var array = [];
        var rows = table.rows('.selected').data();
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            array.push(rows[i].DT_RowId);
        }

        // if array is empty, error pop box warns user
        if (array.length === 0) {
            alert("Please select some student first.");
        } else {
            var courseId = $('#userTable').find('tbody').attr('id');

            // push the id of course inside the array and use it
            array.push(courseId);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Courses/SelectUserPost",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(array),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        }
    });
```

Added this to AJAX and it is not working too

```
success: function() {
  window.location.href = "@Url.Content("~/Courses/Index")";
}
```

Comment: if making the call via ajax the browser wont be aware of the redirect response.

Comment: @Nkosi did you read the bottom part? I have deleted the "success: function()" part from it, use redirect from mvc only, that did not worked too.

Comment: @Nkosi changed the answer for misunderstanding

Comment: I read the question completely. Once you are using ajax the browser is unaware of the response. Even before you edited, the success failed because redirect code is not in the 2xx status but 3xx

Comment: I dont get it, i delete the bottom part, i use top 3 return type and it failed, i added bottom part and used 3 of them and still failed.  @Nkosi

Comment: How shit man, you are right. It is not taking it as a success response. Type an answer as a this, and i ll accept it. I found the answer else but you lead me. @Nkosi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you are using AJAX the browser is unaware of the response.

The AJAX `success` in its current form failed because redirect response code is not in the `2xx` status but `3xx`

You would need to check the actual response and perform the redirect manually based on the location sent in the redirect response.

```
//...
success: function(response) { 
    if (response.redirect) {
        window.location.href = response.redirect;
    } else {
        //...
    }
}

//...
```

#### Update

Working part for anyone who need asap:

Controller Part:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index","Courses");
```

Html part:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Courses/SelectUserPost",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(array),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Successful!");
            window.location.href = "@Url.Content("~/Courses/Index")";
        }
    });
```

Just deleted

> dataType: 'json'

Part because I am using my own data type instead of JSON.

Comment: This and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969476/ajax-success-event-not-working